# Swift - Is using NotificationCenter to observe value change is really bad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

Just a beginner question. I hope someone can help me. I am searching the best way to observe variable change globally in swift. And I encountered some article that says using NotificationCenter is a bad choice and we should avoid it as much as possible. They are suggesting using delegates and dependency injection. I am using delagates for my reusable UI components.

But I have a websocket connection. I received data from this socket every second, this data are being used in different and multiple view controllers (4-6 VCs). Right now, I am using NotificationCenter that notifies all these VCs when I received new data.

Is this the right approach or can you recommend me the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: `NotificationCenter` is a broadcast mechanism for informing unrelated observers of notifications — if multiple unrelated VCs all need to be notified that new data is available, then this is exactly what you'd use `NotificationCenter` for. There _are_ downsides to `NotificationCenter` (it can be a bit difficult to follow cause-and-effect through it because it's such a wide-ranging mechanism), but for many unrelated spots in the app, it can be easier to use a notification than to somehow inject delegates all over the place.

Comment: This question _is_ largely subjective and opinion-based though, so it's not a great fit for SO based on the rules (and I suspect you'll get votes to close this question on that basis.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the deployment target of your app, you could consider using `Combine` to propagate websocket events:

> The Combine framework provides a declarative Swift API for processing values over time. These values can represent many kinds of asynchronous events. Combine declares publishers to expose values that can change over time, and subscribers to receive those values from the publishers.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine